# Pandas: How do I delete first two rows of headers?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I'm using an excel file and would like to drop first two rows of headers that has 3 rows of headers.

Current File Example:

```
    Type1, Type2, Type3, Type4
    SubType1, SubType2, SubType3, SubType4
    SubSubType1-3,,,SubSubType4
0   Blah, Blah1, Blah2, Blah4
1
2
```

After dropping two headers:

```
    SubSubType1-3,,,SubSubType4
0   Blah, Blah1, Blah2, Blah4
1
2
```

I know there are several ways to drop rows using index but I could not find a way to drop first two rows of headers in multiple-header data.

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use header parameter with a value = 2.

```
data = pd.read_csv("file_name.csv", header=2)
```

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I want to edit the existing dataframe, not creating a new one.

Comment: @KevinMorlock: What Muhammad means here is that, while reading your excel to dataframe, use the value header = 2, This would tell pandas that, row 3 of your file is the header and content will be from row 4 onwards.